# How to apply atomocity (0% or100%) prpoerty in data flow task in ssis

Tags: ssis

i have one data flow task in which there is one source and one destination control,and i want to load the data from source to destination using ado.net control.i want to implement the logic that if there is some error occured while loading the data from source to destination,then there should not be load any row in the destination database.if there is no error then it should load fully data.Please advice how can i acheieve this seems impossible task.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use transactions. It's explained pretty well in this article:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

But Distributed Transactions of SSIS can slow down your package, besides Distributed Transactions Coordinator Service must be running on Sql Server.

So you can follow different logic: load your data to a staging table. If it fails, you just truncate the table, and if it will succeed, you can work it further. This will certainly be faster, more transparent, and you can perform some manipulation of your data in staging table in pure SQL before you load it to true destination.

Comment: Hi frik thanks for the answer,but coming of erro chances is very minimal like 2-3% so it can be the any other solution to avoid the load data into staging table?thanks in advance